# list all directly and indirectly imported modules of python

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a bunch of scripts in my python folder. where V10.py is the main file which invokes other python files in the folder. After testing in my laptop, I gave it to the customer. They come back saying it's not working, later I found the reason, two modules "openpyxl" and "scipy" modules are not installed in the customer environment.

In my script, I never imported "openpyxl" & "scipy" these are indirectly imported by "pandas" and "sklearn.cluster" modules. I felt very embarrassed. In the future to avoid these situations. I want to create a script where it will list all the third party modules which I import directly and indirectly. Any ideas how I can proceed on it or is there an existing script available?

Edit1: I gave my customer to have following modules.I listed all the modules I imported.(sys,os,time are default modules but I still listed them)

Modules required:
1. matplotlib
2. numpy
3. os
4. sys
5. pandas
6. sklearn
7. functool
8. itertools
9. time
10.PyPDF2

[image]

Comment: Packages are not loaded into the script/folder. They need to be installed into the Python library that the program is using. A good practice is to use [virtual enviornments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/) and [pip requirements files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id1).

Comment: See the `-v` command line option to the `python` command. And the related `PYTHONVERBOSE` environment variable.

Comment: That's not really your fault. Something is broken on their end if their `pandas` installation isn't providing its requirements.

Comment: What instructions did) you give your customer to install Pandas and scikit-learn? Dependencies will usually be installed when you use `pip install`, but do read the respective package [installation instructions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html).

Comment: Rather than try to list *all* imported modules, worry about direct requirements. You may want to use [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), give your customer the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files, and give them instructions on how to use `pipenv install`. That makes sure they get the *exact same versions you have*.